# .Net Solution Structure for ArcObjects and Geodatabase programming

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase

OK - I understand that this is a bit subjective - but you're the best community forum I've got!

So, we are talking about starting a fresh customisation for ArcGIS or a Windows app using Engine.
I often become a little perplexed when trying to create nice clean layers of abstraction between my GUI, business objects and data access layer (geodatabase access).

It often works out like something below:

[image]

- The **PresentationLayer** makes calls in BusinessLayer to get data from
  database and give back wrapped up in some form of business object -
  it is never a ValueObject straight fresh from the database.
- In **BusinessLayer** - I have all my business logic that accesses
  DataLayer for data from the geodatabase (it gets back data from the geodatabase via
  ValueObjects - DataLayer also uses this assembly).
- In **ValueObjects** assembly, this is just a set of objects that map directly to SDE tables and do nothing else.
- **Core** is where the program starts and shows forms etc.
- **Common** is just a place to put things that are useful to use here and
  there, usually static methods etc.

Does this look sane? How do you structure your solutions?

Answer (score 4):

I like very much to talk about ArcObjects and that kind of discussion, but people may not find it suitable here.

Well I always have a project for specific, ArcObjects code only. That means I can reuse these methods and classes anywhere else. (sounds like your Common).

This is how I do it:

- Solution

  - Business Project

    - Models (this is how I name the mapping between features and objects);
    - Repositories
    - Other business code
  - Business Test Project
  - AO Specific Code (I generally call it Company.Project.GIS and it divide it following the main namespaces ESRI has. This project cannot ever never reference the Business Project. If you need to build a geometry aggregator, or a tool that works commonly, build it here, and consume it on the business layer)

    - esriSystem
    - Carto
    - Display
    - Geodatabase
    - Geometry
    - Authentication (this is a custom part, that handles, for example, authentication against a table in a geodatabase - but it could be anything else);
  - AO Specific Code Test Project
  - UI Project

    - Forms
    - Controls
    - Extension
    - Commands
    - Tools
    - Dockables
    - etc
  - UI Test Project

I try to separate UI project from Business Project, but sometimes with legacy code you can't just bring them apart and I always create **separate projects for unit testing**.

Comment: +1 for "Well I always have a project for specific, ArcObjects code only." we also isolate AO code into a common assembly so all developers can use the functionality without having to use or import AO assemblys into their projects. But we also allow the developer to use AO for specific functionality in some solutions as long as the project are named properly so we easily can find the projects that need to be updated when we get a new version of AGE.

Answer (score 3):

Dave Bouwman wrote a helpful series 5 yrs ago about this.  I would be *very* interested in hearing how his methodology has evolved since then.

[Geodatabase Kung-Fu: Geo-Business Objects](http://blog.davebouwman.com/2006/07/26/geodatabase-kung-fu-geo-business-objects/)

[Code Generation + Geodatabase = Goodness](http://blog.davebouwman.com/2006/09/01/code-generation-geodatabase-goodness/)

[.NET Databinding the Geodatabase](http://blog.davebouwman.com/2006/09/02/net-databinding-the-geodatabase/)

Comment: Cheers Kirk - will check this out - think I have looked at it in the past but probably worth another look.

Comment: I have also seen this: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/a6eb84fb-93db-4bc3-82a9-874d8890a8ca.htm  - Don't know whether you have ever tinkered with this approach?

Comment: I played a couple of yrs ago with inheriting from BindingList, but I don't think I used this sample.  Where it gets messy is when you need to deal with subtyped featureclasses where you want the UI to display choices for particular field where the field has different domains depending on the subtype.